# LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions i get this error each time i run ndk-build in terminal

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

HERES MY ANDROID.MK FILE
    i ran android ndk-build and got an error that says" ndk-buld command not found" then i later exported my path using 
"export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/mac15/android-ndk-r11c" and since then i have spent days googling possible resolutions and have gotten none that actually work.

```
    LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libavcodec
    LIBJPEG_PATH := path-to-libjpeg
    LEPTONICA_PATH := path-to-leptonica  
    TESSERACT_PATH := path-to-tesseract
    LOCAL_MODULE := hello-jni
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    TESSERACT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
    LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
    LIBJPEG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libjpeg
    LIBPNG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng
    # Just build the Android.mk files in the subdirs
    include $(call all-subdir-makefiles) 
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    TESSERACT_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../external/tesseract-3.01
    LEPTONICA_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../external/leptonica-1.68
    LIBJPEG_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../external/libjpeg
```

Comment: ooh i figured it out, the files that i was using to build my tess-two where for eclipse, and so be sure not to use eclipse test-two files when you are using android studio

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? I am getting same error and tried so many things and checked so many SO threads , I am unable to fix this issue. I getting this error when I am building jsoncpp , source code I got it from following link https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp and I am getting following error each time I do ndk-build Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions
Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension